# При клике на тег p поменять название внутри(React)?

Tags: reactjs

```
        '<p className="header___icon__name">
          Hot<b className="header___icon__name_text">Skins</b>
        </p>'
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что у меня таких p много в коде и через state менять его проблематично(создавать массив, и по индексам обращаться ?). Через dom хотел поменять, но не получается

Comment: Комментарий в начало вопроса лучше перенесите. Больше шанс на ответ.